# Why is my XUnit Test succeeding when it should fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a unit test that I'm trying to build, that should check for other Organisation names and throw out an error message if they already exist (it needs to be unique).

Could someone tell me why this keeps asserting as True when it should be False?

```
[Fact]
    public async Task IsValid_ReturnsFalse_WhenNameAlreadyExists()
    {
        // Arrange
        var input = new Organisation
        {
            Name = "TestClient",
            Id = "TestOrg"
        };
        var mockOrganisationService = new Mock<IOrganisationService>();
        mockOrganisationService
            .Setup(x => x.GetOrganisationByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((Organisation)null);
        var inputCopy = new Organisation
        {
            Name = "TestClient",
            Id = "TestOrg"
        };
        var myValidation = new ClientValidation(mockOrganisationService.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await myValidation.IsValid(input);
        var resultCopy = await myValidation.IsValid(inputCopy);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(result.Valid);
        Assert.False(resultCopy.Valid);
    }
```

Comment: _"Could someone tell me why this keeps asserting as True when it should be False?"_ - it does because you told it to : `.Setup(x => x.GetOrganisationByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((Organisation)null)`. Means: **Whatever input, return `null`**. So, your second entity will pass for uniqueness, because your mocked service does not "return" your first entity.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why your validator is responsible for getting the organisation. It should be provided an organization to validate, period.

Comment: Hi @Fildor, thanks for the response. I did notice this too but I'm still scratching my head, as removing it puts `Organisation` into null. Apologies if this is easy to fix, I'm new to Unit Testing and to testing APIs in general.

Comment: Hi @madreflection, I have done that under the //Act part of the Unit Test. The Interface, to my knowledge, exists to check any Organisations that already exist and returns them by Name.

Comment: I don't think you have a long way to go. Just realise: A mocked service does not behave like a real service. It does _exactly and only_ what it has been told to do. In this case that would be "whatever name you are given - you don't know him!". So you actually may want to split this test: 1. Name is unknown 2. Name exists. The latter one needs a different setup of the mock: it should actually return an Organisation.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The problem I see with this, from a maintainability standpoint, is that the validator is specific to a "create organisation" action, but you haven't named it as such, so it takes investigation to comprehend its purpose when someone new has to look at it. The payload for creating a new object is often different from the one for updating it - those should be different types with different validators.

Comment: ^^ Right. Because Create: Name needs to not exist. Update: Name _can_ exist if it is not the updated property but the entity that is being updated. But if it _is_ the updated property, there can be no _other_ entity by that name already.

Comment: Another issue with this test is that you only validate `input`; you never add it to whatever data store `organisationService` uses. So if the test was meant to disallow creation/update of an organisation using `inputCopy` because of the name conflict, the data store has nothing to conflict with it and `inputCopy` passes validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've been going about it all wrong, the Moq can't return an Organisation to validate against another as it can only handle it one at a time. I was misinformed by my dev. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

```
[Fact]
    public async Task IsValid_ReturnsTrue_WhenCreatingANewClient()
    {
        // Arrange
        var input = new Organisation
        {
            Name = "TestClient",
            Id = "TestOrg"
        };
        var mockOrganisationService = new Mock<IOrganisationService>();
        mockOrganisationService
            .Setup(x => x.GetOrganisationNameAsync(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(() => new ValueTask<Organisation>(input));
        var myValidation = new ClientValidation(mockOrganisationService.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await myValidation.IsValid(input);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(result.Valid);
    }
```